# Spring Boot custom annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

In all of my projects I need the same WebSecurityConfig. So I copy the same implementation of extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

I like to add this to a common library I am using in every project and create a annotation for that.
But the annotation class cannot have a superclass.

I tried this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public @interface EnableGlobalSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

Is there a better way to get this working? I just want to add my SecurityConfiguration by adding an annotation or something similar.

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you want a general security configuration and keep it as a `jar` then use this configuration by annotating any project with for example `@EnableGlobalSecurity` and have security set up?

Comment: yes exactly. I have the same security Option in all of my project (for example with path need fully authenticated users and which can be access by all.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just [@Import](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html) your shared `@Configuration` class in every application that should use it.

Another way would be to [create a custom auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.x/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration). This way, declaring a dependency on your shared library would suffice.